# Magento 1.9.2 wysiwyg editors not showing in CMS page

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

Editors are not showing in content area, Need a help. Can any help me? It's badly needed help.

Comment: any consolve error

Comment: Console not generating. and message "No Javascript on this page"

Comment: I told browser consolve error

Comment: browser consolve error not showing, is there any reason to hide content block. I mean any code block making this type error.

Comment: Open admin, go to System -> Configuration -> Content Management->check it's WYSIWYG Editor Enable or not

Comment: System -> Configuration -> Content Management is enable

Comment: Did you insatll any extension recentely

Comment: yes, Mage store reward points

Comment: Please disable and see it's working or not

Comment: I have been tried with disable the extension, but not working.

Comment: Then sorry bro No idea without seeing anything i can't tell sorry

Comment: it is working rest of thing like product, static block etc, but CMS page not working.

Comment: Hi Anwar, can you inspect the page source and see if the block is there in the background? We had an issue like this previously and there was some erroneous code in index.php that caused it.

Comment: code block not showing. showing only single <tr>

Answer (score 0):

The wysiwyg editor in 1.9.x uses Flash - makes sure it's enabled in the browser. For Chrome, you want it set to "Always enable for this site."

Comment: Check this one and tell us @anwar

Answer (score 0):

Open it in incognito mode and tell us whether it shows or not

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/177807)

Comment: It does, because It could be due to cache that persists the cause of the problem